# What's the difference between new object[] {} and new [] {}?

Tags: c#

Sometimes when passing an arbitrary array of objects such as to an Activator, I see this notation:

```
new [] {5, "Five"}
```

And in other cases, that seem to need a named dictionary of objects, I see this:

```
new {Numeric = 5, Textual = "Five"}
```

What exactly is this second expression creating an array of?

Comment: The second example isn't valid.  It's not the proper syntax for an anonymous type, nor is it the proper syntax for an array declaration.  Without valid code we cannot say what it's referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is an array of `object`s. It contains two objects: an `int` `5` and a `string` `"Five"`. The second is an array of an anonymous type. It contains one object. The one object has two properties, `int Numeric` with a value of `5`, and `string Textual` with a value of `"Five"`.

The second is much more explicit and type-safe, but being an anonymous type, not useful outside of a local context; the first could be useful in certain cases, e.g. passing arguments to a method via reflection.

Answer (score 4):

First code produces an array of objects.

Second code doesn't compile, actually. If you meant `new [] { new { Numeric = 5, Textual = "Five"} }` then it's an array of anonymous type, but you should clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Second declaration looks like anonymous type, but it won't compile. It seems that you want to have array of anonymous objects, which you can create like this:

```
var anonArray = new[] { new { Numeric = 5, Textual = "Five" }, 
                        new { Numeric = 6, Textual = "Six" }};
```

[Anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is
>   not available at the source code level. The type of each property is
>   inferred by the compiler.

Comment: Isn't the second actually an array that contains one element of an anonymous type?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The second example doesn't compile; it's not the proper syntax for an array of an anonymous type.  You'd need two sets of curly braces and another `new` for that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for answering Servy. Nevertheless I've edited my answer to add proper anonymous type declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is creating an array of type `object` and putting an integer and a string inside of it.

The second example is creating an array (of size one) of an anonymous type.  (When no type is provided for the array (`new []`) it will attempt to infer the type that should be used based on the most derived type common to all elements in the array initialization.)  The `new {Numeric = 5, Textual = "Five"}` is creating a new anonymous type with two properties, `Numeric` of type `int` (the type is inferred based on what is assigned to it) and with a value of `5`, and a property `Textual` of type `string` and value `"Five"`.